# how to use alarm manager to update service every hour in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

**I have a problem with using of alarm manger to update my service because I don't know the true location to put this peas of code :**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("updateOptions", 0);
        int updatePeriod=sp.getInt("UpdatePeriod", -1);


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent i = new Intent(this, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), updatePeriod, pintent);
```

**In the fact my task is to update my app widget by the total number of the new items if there are new items in the xml file ( news feed ) :**

[image]

**to perform that I used 2 classes :**

**1- UpdateWidgetService :**

```
package com.example.testfeeds;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

  public static int numberOfItems=0;



  //numberOfItems=0;
    private static  String LOG = "testwidgets";



    ArrayList<String> feedsPubDate;

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
      public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG, "Called");
        // Create some random data

        feedsPubDate=new ArrayList<String>(); 


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("updateOptions", 0);
        int updatePeriod=sp.getInt("UpdatePeriod", -1);


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent i = new Intent(this, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), updatePeriod, pintent);





        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
            .getApplicationContext());

        int[] allWidgetIds = intent
            .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
            MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
        Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
          // Create some random data



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       

          RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
              .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
              R.layout.widget_layout);

          Log.d("numberOfItems intially", String.valueOf(numberOfItems));

              try {
                numberOfItems=doTestFeed();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          // Set the text
          remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.title3,Color.WHITE);
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title3,"  "+
              String.valueOf(numberOfItems));

          Log.w(LOG, String.valueOf(numberOfItems));


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          

          // Register an onClickListener
          Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
              MyWidgetProvider.class);

          clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
          clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
              allWidgetIds);

          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent,
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.title3, pendingIntent);
          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
      }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    int doTestFeed() throws MalformedURLException, ParseException

    {  
        Log.d("msg"," in do test feed");

        InputStream is = null;
        int x = 0;

        URL myURL = new URL("http://yunn.yu.edu.jo/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=55&layout=blog&Itemid=104&format=feed&type=rss");
        try {
            URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();
             is = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(is, null);
                Log.d("msg","before making parsing");
                x=parseXML(parser);
                Log.d("msg","after making parsing");
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.d("msg"," done testing");
        return x;
    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private int parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException, ParseException
    {

        Log.d("msg"," in parser");

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        int getElement=0;
        String pubDate=null;






        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

            String tagName = null;


            switch (eventType){

            //----------------------------------//
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT: 
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                break;
           //----------------------------------//
             case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
             { tagName = parser.getName();
                 if ("item".equals(tagName)){
                      getElement=1;
                 } else if (getElement!=0){

                      if ("pubDate".equals(tagName)){
                         pubDate= parser.nextText();

                         feedsPubDate.add(pubDate);
                         Log.d("value",pubDate);
                     }
                 }
             }
                 break;                     
           //----------------------------------//
             case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
             { tagName = parser.getName();
                 if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && getElement != 0){

                 }
             }
                 break;

          //----------------------------------//


            }// end-switch.


            eventType= parser.next();

        }// end-while.

        int i=0;

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("tempData", 0);
        String dateStringA=sp.getString("recentPubDate", null);

        Log.d("oldest date",dateStringA);

        for(String s : feedsPubDate )

        {

        String dateStringB = feedsPubDate.get(i);
        SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateA = parserSDF.parse(dateStringA);
        Date dateB = parserSDF.parse(dateStringB);
        if (dateA.compareTo(dateB) < 0) {


            Log.d("imp msg","one new item");

            numberOfItems++;
        }

        i++;

        }


        Log.d("update result", String.valueOf(numberOfItems));


      // Toast.makeText(GeneralNews.this,"The size of the list"+feedsTitles.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   return numberOfItems;

    } //end xmlParser method.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

**2- MyWidgetProvider:**

```
package com.example.testfeeds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.view.Menu;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

     private static final String LOG = "testwidgets";

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
          int[] appWidgetIds) {



        Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
        // Get all ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        // Build the intent to call the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
            UpdateWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        // Update the widgets via the service
        context.startService(intent);
      }

}
```

**The result isn't correct : problem 1 --> every second the update service is called while the update period is 3600000 ms !!
problem 2 --> once the update service is called the "numberOfItems" incremented by one !! even if there are no items its dates newest for my app !!
actually I can't point out the logical error ! is it the location of using of alarm manager is the problem ??**

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Handler`, see below:

```
private int mSampleDurationTime = 3600000; // 1 hour
private boolean continueToRun = true;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();

mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);
```

where `mRunnable` is your task:

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

 //...
public void run() {

   // do your stuff here, like update
   // this block of code you going to reach every 1 hour

   if(continueToRun == true){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);
   }

 }
    ...
};
```

First time you call `postDelayed` and invoke `new Runnable()`. After, if you want to continue,
call the same method into `run()`

Comment: in any class should I put this peas of code? how I can   update the widget by using this code ?

Comment: You can use handler in main Activity or from Service. Handler is like Timer from where you can run any command after some period of time

Answer (score 1):

> problem 1 --> every second the update service is called while the
>   update period is 3600000 ms

Are you sure that

> int updatePeriod=sp.getInt("UpdatePeriod", -1);

returns `3600000` ? If it returns `-1`, it means that your `UpdatePeriod` has been saved correctly before calling the service and `setRepeating` would be called every `cal.getTimeInMillis()` meaning endlessly

`problem 2 --> once the update service is called the "numberOfItems" incremented by one !! even if there are no items its dates newest for my app !!`
Try this

```
if (dateA.compareTo(dateB) <= 0)
```

instead of

```
if (dateA.compareTo(dateB) < 0)
```

Like you, I would use an alarm to call the AppWdiget's receiver. But I use `Alarm#set` instead of `setRepeating` to avoid problems if there is a bug in the time calculation (as you seem to be experiencing). 
So every time I receive the intent from my first alarm, I set 1 other alarm  to fire in `now()+interval`

Comment: yes its -1 ... how to fix the problem << problem # 1 with this code

Comment: Just to test your alarm manager if it works or not, you can use int updatePeriod=sp.getInt("UpdatePeriod", 3600000); So if the UpdatePeriod preference doesn exist, it will return 3600000